# automatically arranging gwt buttons depending on size

Tags: java, gwt, layout, button

I'm new to GWT and therefore need help with the following:

I am working with UIBinder and need to arrange three gwt buttons with dynamic labels in a special way (see picture attached). How do I do this? I'm grateful for any help!

[image]

Comment: Do you need to adjust each button's width to finally make them look like your picture or you are just looking for a way to just make them go next to each other and if there is no room on the line for one button it should just go on the next line? Because in the latter case you can just accomplish it by giving your buttons a a fixed width and set them to `float: left;`.

Comment: It is supposed to look exactly as on the picture. `float:left;` wouldn't work, since I want the buttons to fill the whole horizontal space available. For example: the area where I'd like to place the buttons is 300px wide. Button 1 has a width of 250px. Button 2 won't fit next to Button 1, so Button 1 gets a width of 300px and Button 2 and 3 go to the next line.

Comment: But that's exactly what `float: left;` will do... or am I misunderstanding something. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/heC6Z/

Comment: damn. I'm beeing stupid today :D It's too early in the morning I guess ^^ thanks for the hint... I've been looking for some GWT layout to do a simple css task. argh.

Comment: ok no, again I'm being stupid. `float:left;` does not do what I need. In case that button 1 is too large for button 2 to fit next to it, I want button 1 to occupy available space (in the above example: 300px - even though it actually would only need 250 to display it's label) and button 2 and 3 to fill all the space (e.g. 300px) in the second line (button 3 has a fixed size, but button 1 and 2 are dynamic).

Comment: I updated my answer with the algorithm to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment you just arrange your widgets with an additional CSS style to float them left. As a GWT container, there is [FlowPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html).

CSS:

```
.yourWidget {
  float: left;
  ..other styles..
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Code:

```
YourButtonWidget w1 = new YourButtonWidget("Some long label");
w1.addStyleNames("yourWidget"):
YourButtonWidget w2 = new YourButtonWidget("Label");
w2.addStyleNames("yourWidget"):
YourButtonWidget w3 = new YourButtonWidget("Another Label");
w3.addStyleNames("yourWidget"):

FlowPanel container = new FlowPanel();
container.add(w1);
container.add(w2);
container.add(w3);
```

Obviously you can integrate the CSS style as part of your widget representing your button. Just remember that your widget must assign a width to itself or `float: left;` obviously won't work.

***UPDATE:*** I just read your last comment, for that you would have to just develop an algorithm to adjust the button 1 and 2 width to fill all available space in the container. `float: left;` will stil work, you just have to work out the size of the buttons.

With 3 buttons it's easy (where button1Width and button2Width are dynamic and button3Width is fixed), here is how to work out the final widths (continuing from above):

```
int containerWidth = container.getElement().getOffsetWidth();
int button1Width = w1.getElement().getOffsetWidth();
int button2Width = w2.getElement().getOffsetWidth();
int button3Width = w3.getElement().getOffsetWidth();

if ( (button1Width + button2Width) > containerWidth ) {
  button1Width = containerWidth;
  if (( button2Width + button3Width ) > containerWidth) {
    button2Width = containerWidth;
  } else {
    button2Width = containerWidth - button3Width;
  }
} else {
  button2Width = containerWidth - button1Width;
}

w1.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(button1Width,Unit.PX);
w2.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(button2Width,Unit.PX);
w3.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(button3Width,Unit.PX);
```

Just make sure that you do these adjustments *after* you attach everything to the DOM, otherwise the widths will not be available obviously.

Comment: Thanks ;) I'll try something like this. I thought, maybe there is some fancy GWT layout that does this kind of stuff...

Comment: It's such a specific and narrow case, that I doubt any framework or toolkit would have such capabilities. You also have to remember that GWT is not a framework. It's a *toolkit*, so it gives you the building tools to build your own frameworks and capabilities.